# Can the minimum time to schedule tasks be found without brute force?

Tags: list, math, optimization, scheduled-tasks, code-complexity

If I have a list of integers representing the time it takes for a task to be completed and I have x workers that can only work on one task until the time it takes to complete is up, can I find the minimum time it could possibly take in a best case scenario? I do not need the exact permutation that makes up this minimum completion time, just the time.

For example, to make it simple, if I have a list [2, 4, 6] and I have 2 workers then if I start with 2 and 4 then when 2 finishes 6 will start meaning that it will take 8 seconds to complete all tasks. However if I start with 6 and 2 then when 2 finishes 4 will start and finish at the same time as 6, therefore the tasks only take 6 seconds if done in this order.

Is there a way of knowing that it will only take 6 seconds that is better than n! or brute force complexity that guarantees it is the minimum time possible? Thank you for any help in advance please feel free to ask questions if I left out any details or you're confused!

edit: please help :(

edit 2: is it even possible? Anyone know?

Comment: I think in this case, finding the "minimum time it could possibly take in a best-case scenario" requires the same amount of effort as determining the order that tasks should be performed (i.e determining the permutation). I haven't thought too much about this problem, but it reminds me of the [Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). However, finding a **minimum lower-bound** is a simpler problem and I think that's the term you're looking for instead of "best-case".

Comment: agreed, the reason I want the minimum time is so instead of iterating to n! to find the best permutation I can iterate til I find the minimum time and then break so I was just wondering if there was maybe some formula or something out there to determine the minimum time in anything less than n!. Cheers on informing me of the knapsack problem that's quite interesting @Dai

Comment: BTW, you might also want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm as I think your problem is a an instance of that scheduling problem where all workers have the same cost for each task - in which case you can find the best solution (no need for finding bounds) in at most `O(n^4)` time provided (where `n == workers * tasks`) which is better than `O(n!)`.

Comment: You're looking for the *makespan* for the collection of tasks.  There is a lot of prior work to review.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark do you happen to know where I can find this work to review? I've done some research and thank you for informing me of the term makespan that helps a lot but pretty much every algorithm I can find on it involves some stipulation like x task must be completed before y and I have no such stipulation on my program so their algorithms aren't of much help to me. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a single worker, then the actual total time required is the same as the sum of all task times.

```
jobs = [ 2, 4, 6, etc... ]
time_required = SUM( jobs )
```

In the case of two workers, then **given a specific ordering** of jobs the total-time required can be determined by first assigning each task's required time to whichever worker has the current lowest sum associated with it, then getting the highest sum associated with each worker:

```
define type worker  = vector<time_t>
define type workers = min_priority_queue<worker> using worker.sum() # so the current worker.sum() (the sum of `time_t` values in `vector<time_t>`) is the priority-queue key.
define type task    = int

jobs = [ 2, 4, 6, etc... ]

# Use two workers:
workers.add( new worker )
workers.add( new worker )

# Iterate once through each job:
foreach( task t in jobs ) {

    minWorker = workers.getMinWorker() # priority queue "find-min" operation
    minWorker.add( t )
}

# Determine which worker will work the longest time:
time_required = workers.getMaxWorker().sum() # priority queue "find-max" operation
```

Because this is an actual solution, then the `time_required` is a point-sample that exists between the upper and lower-bounds - which isn't exactly what you're after, but because it can be computed in `O(n)` time it's a good starting point.

The above algorithm can then be generalised to any number of workers just by adding them to the priority queue - as heap-based priority queues' `find-min` operation is `O(1)` I believe this algorithm runs in `O(n)` time where `n` is the number of jobs, independent of the number of workers. (I may be wrong about the precise runtime complexity).

As for computing bounds in less time than `O(n!)` time... that's tricky (at least for me, as it's been a few years since I last cracked-open [my copy of CLRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms)).

A minimal lower-bound for `x` workers for *any* order of jobs is simply the largest single value in the job set.

A maximal upper-bound for `x` workers for *any* order of jobs *could* be the sum of the largest `100 * (1/x) %` of jobs (so given 2 workers it's the sum of the largest 50% jobs, for 3 workers it's the sum of the largest 33% jobs, for 4 workers it's 25%, etc). This will require you to sort the set first (taking `O(n log n)` if using Quicksort).

```
jobs = [ 2, 4, 6, etc... ]

worker_count = 2

jobs.sortDescending() # O(n log n)

# if there's 50 jobs and 2 workers, then take the first 25 jobs and sum them...
# ...that's an upper_bound for the time required to complete all tasks by 2 workers, as it assumes that 1 unlucky worker will get all of the longest tasks

upper_bound = jobs.take( jobs.count / worker_count ).sum()
```

Comment: Good solution, finding the sum of the first half of the tasks (in the case of 2 workers) won't always be the minimum though unfortunately, in the case of [8,2,2,2] the best solution is 8 seconds but the sum of the first half of largest numbers is 10. And any sort of sorting won't help unless I can know the minimum possible time prior otherwise it'll be impossible to know when to break out. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @mizuprogrammer My post said that finding the sum of the first half of descending-sorted values would yield an upper-bound, not a lower-bound.

Comment: ah my apologies you are correct I misread, your solution is right but for the lower bound it won't always be the largest number in the set since I can't assume that I'll always have as many workers as I do tasks. Thanks for all the help! :) @Dai